# Hibernate, Oracle, Join Tables and Key Issues

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have 3 tables, `Parent`, `Child` and `ParentChild` which joins the first two together. When doing an insert (`Parent.getChilds().add(new Child());`) I get an error because, apparently, the primary key hasn't been created and I get a constraint violation:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TU.SYS_C0072908) violated - parent key not found
```

If I let my test case rollback, this works fine, I don't get a constraint violation, and all of my assertions pass. If I set my test case to not roll back I get the above error. Also, if the Parent and Child were created outside of the current transaction then everything works peachy-keen. I.e.:

```
Parent parent = parentDao.get(parentId);
Child child = childDao.get(childId);
parent.getChilds().add(child);
child.setParent(parent);
parentDao.save(parent);
```

Mappings look like this:

Parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.whatev">
    <class name="Parent">
        <id name="parentId">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <set name="childs" table="ParentChild" cascade="all">
            <key column="parentId"/>
            <many-to-many class="Child" column="childId" unique="true"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Child

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.whatev">
    <class name="Child">
        <id name="childId">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <join table="ParentChild" inverse="true">
            <key column="childId"/>
            <many-to-one name="Parent" column="parentId" not-null="true"/>
        </join>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

A `Parent` can have more than one `Child` and a `Child` can have only one `Parent`. (It has been pointed out that there should be no join table and, instead, be a `PARENTID` column in the `CHILD` table but this design decision is not mine to make.)

Tables are pretty straight forward as well:

```
CREATE TABLE PARENT (
    PARENTID NUMBER(38) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(PARENTID)
);

CREATE TABLE CHILD (
    CHILDID NUMBER(38) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(CHILDID)
);

CREATE TABLE PARENTCHILD (
    PARENTID NUMBER(38) NOT NULL,
    CHILDID NUMBER(38) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(PARENTID) REFERENCES PARENT(PARENTID),
    FOREIGN KEY(CHILDID) REFERENCES CHILD(CHILDID),
    UNIQUE (PARENTID, CHILDID)
);
```

The primary keys are populated by sequences through a trigger when the record is created.

What's wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the trigger applying the sequence nextval.

By specifying `native` but not telling hibernate about the sequence, hibernate thinks it has to come up with the id itself since Oracle doesn't have anything to natively create unique ids. `Child.childId` will have the nextval from the sequence (because of the trigger overwriting what hibernate comes up with) and `ParentChild.childId` gets the value that hibernate assigns, creating a constraint issue.

To handle this in a cross-database-friendly way, either drop the trigger, keep the sequence and let Oracle handle the ids:

```
<id name="childId">
    <generator class="native">
        <param name="sequence">CHILDID_SEQ</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

Or drop the trigger and sequence and let hibernate assign the ids:

```
<id name="childId">
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>
```

Answer (score 2):

"A Parent can have more than one Child and a Child can have only one Parent."

Then you shouldn't have a parentchild table, as a join table is only needed to resolve many to many relationships.

The child table should simply contain a PARENTID column with the foreign key to the parent table.

Comment: While I agree with you, the DB design is out of my hands. According to the [hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-bidirectional-join-12m) this should work.